# How can I find out what index is the table I want to import from a web page?

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets

Need some help with `importhtml()` function as I am trying to import table from html that has many tables. Its syntax is this:

`IMPORTHTML(url, query, index)`

What I don't understand is how can I find out what index is the table I want to import from HTML? Shouldn't there be an attribute for table element that says: OK, you are table number 8 on this page. I doubt I have go through entire html and count how many tables there are before the one I need.

Basically, I need to find out on what should I be concentrating on when going through html which hold desired table.

Answer (score 8):

From the web page, from google developers console enter below to find table numbers

---

```
var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
   function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });
```

---

```
var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("list"), 
   function(x) { console.log(i++, x); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Url<-'Your URL'
Website <- read_html(Url)

Website%>%
  html_nodes("table")%>%
  length()
```

This is also a way to count the tables quite easily. However, it doesn't index your specific table.